# Forking a project from GitHub to CocoaPods

Tags: git, github, cocoapods

I'm new to GitHub and have forked [this project](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK) (One-Signal) on my own repository, [here](https://github.com/fraxool/OneSignal-iOS-SDK). I have updated some files in my repository directly on GitHub to be able to use these changes into my XCode project with CocoaPods. So I have added this line in my podfile :

```
pod 'OneSignal', :git => 'https://github.com/fraxool/OneSignal-iOS-SDK.git'
```

I have installed it with the command `pod install` but I'm still not able to use the new methods I have added to the files on GitHub. Here is what I can see in my "Pods" directory, in XCode :

[image]

It seems like it is using the OneSignal.framework file from the GitHub repository, however, I have directly edited the source files located in the directory "OneSignal" ([here](https://github.com/fraxool/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/iOS_SDK/OneSignal)), not "Framework".

So how could I fix that so I can use the changes from my repository into my XCode project ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to make a commit with your new code compiled in the [OneSignal.framework](https://github.com/fraxool/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/iOS_SDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework) as cocoapods uses this instead of the source. It looks like you forgot the main compiled [OneSignal binary](https://github.com/fraxool/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/iOS_SDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework/Versions/A/OneSignal)

You may also need to update OneSignal.podspec to a new version and tag your latest commit with the same version number.

I also reviewed your commits, it should let you disable the auto resetting of the badge number by the SDK however the 'increase' option on OneSignal will no longer be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally fixed it! About the second issue, I will now be able to work deeper in the code to fix it too.